# Counter JavaScript Code with Commas

Tags: javascript, joomla, module

I currently have a plug-in on my Joomla site that is a "counter" where I enter in my numbers and it will count from 0 upwards. I need to accomplish this without the extension and I was wondering if someone knows the code I need to enter in to my custom module to accomplish the result.

Attached is a picture of the current state of the counter on the front end.

I would like the counter to display the numbers with a "$" sign before and a "+" sign after the number. I would also like it to add commas once it counts in to the thousands/millions to help with legibility. 
e.g. $5,000,000 +

Would anyone be kind enough to assist me with the needed code to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

[image: current front end pic]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JavaScript code that will add commas to the number

```
        //this is the number you are displaying
        var myNumber = 1000000;
        var myArr=[];

        function addCommas(myNumber) {
            myArr = myNumber.toString().split('');
            for (i=myArr.length-3;i>0;i=i-3) {
                myArr.splice(i,0,",");
            }
        }

        //Call the function to add commas to the number
        addCommas(myNumber);
```